# Minimization problem as PDE

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, optimization, image-processing, gradient-flows

In the article "An Image Interpolation Scheme for Repetitive Structures" Luong, Ledda and Philips propose the following approach to denoising digital image.

They consider that regularized total variation minimization problem
$$\hat I(x)=\arg\min_{I(x)}[f(\nabla I(x))+\lambda\cdot g(H*I(x)-I_0(x))] \tag{3}$$
can be transformed to the partial differential equation:
$$\frac{\partial I(x, t)}{\partial t}=f_{I}' (\nabla I(x, t))+\lambda \cdot g_{I}'(H*I(x, t)-I(x, 0))) \tag{4}$$
I can't find foundation of such transformation and I can't agree with the equivalence of these two problems.

Moreover the researchers believe appropriate to take $f(\cdot)=||\cdot||_{L^2}$ (or maybe $||\cdot||_{L^1}$) and $g(\cdot)=||\cdot||_{L^1}$. And I can't understand how they're going to find corresponding derivatives in such case.

Could you help me understand these considerations?

Comment: By the way, are you aware of [dsp.SE] site? I think it may be of interest to you if you work with image processing.

Comment: Thanks! I'll keep it in mind.

Comment: I think the idea is that $\hat{I}$ is a functional -- it takes a function $x$ as input and returns a real number as output.  The calculus of variations teaches us how to minimize functionals.  You write down the Euler-Lagrange equations and it gives you a differential equation you have to solve.  I'm guessing the Euler-Lagrange equations here will lead to something similar to (4) -- basically we want the right hand side of (4) to be $0$.  Btw, if you just want to denoise or deblur an image there are probably better approaches, like the Pock-Chambolle algorithm for example.

Answer (score 4):

First, this is an engineering paper, not a math paper. One shouldn't expect rigorous math from engineers.

Second, I don't think they take $f(\cdot)=\|\cdot\|_{L^2}$. They use "the total
variation (TV): $\rho_R(I(x, t)) = |\nabla I(x, t)|$". Which is basically the $L^1$ norm of the gradient.

Third, what they really mean by

> The minimization problem of equation 3 could be transformed to the following
>   partial diﬀerential equation (pde) which produces iteratively diffused images
>   $I(x, t)$ starting from the initialisation image $I(x,0)$

is that they are going to run gradient descent in search for minimizer.  In their words, "the pde of equation 4 is iteratively applied to update the blurred and
noisy image in the restoration process." The right hand side of (4) should have a minus sign, otherwise it looks like they are going for maximum instead of minimum.

As for how they are going to take the derivative of non-differentiable functions - in the actual computation it's a finite difference of some sort.

Comment: Ok, maybe you're right and $f(\cdot)=||\cdot||_{L^1}$. Can you give your mathematical interpretations of $f'_x(\nabla I(x))$ and $g'_x(H*I(x)-I_0(x))$ in such case?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. But now it seems to me that the derivatives are taken with respect to $I(x)$.

Comment: @Max Yes, they are with respect to the functional. Example: if you are minimizing $I(f)=\int |\nabla f|^p$, then the derivative in direction $\psi$ is $-\int \psi\,\mathrm{div}(|\nabla f|^{p-2}\nabla f)$. Since you want to minimize $I$, you pick the direction $\psi$ in which $I$ decreases the fastest: namely, a multiple of $\mathrm{div}(|\nabla f|^{p-2}\nabla f)$.  This can be expressed as a parabolic problem $f_t=\mathrm{div}(|\nabla f|^{p-2}\nabla f)$, a form of heat equation.